# Saving item of a listview before screen orientation using an activity

Tags: android, android-listview

Have searched around on saving item populated by a listview but the results i found all used fragment which in any case i tried without success.
Am trying to do a simple thing save text which are gotten from a webserver to my listview so when orientation is called the text populated in the listview doesn't disappear.

Am adding text to my listview like this 'listview.add(text);'

Have tried saving the text in onsave and populating it again in oncreate but doesn't work.
Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you used `onSaveInstanceState()`?

Comment: You should read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Orientation change causes configuration change.

From [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) "Handling configuration changes" section

> When such a change occurs, Android recreates the running activity (the system calls onDestroy(), then immediately calls onCreate()).

So, save in onDestroy().

---

Move codes (to save data) in onSaveInstanceState() to onDestroy()

This sample uses onDestroy() but onPause() (or onStop() if minSdkVersion is heigh enough) may be a good choice.
(as it is a normal place to save someting.)

```
// Your save code (may be onother name)
private void save(String text)
{
    ....
}

// onSaveInstanceState() is NOT part of Activity life cycle.
onSaveInstanceState()
{
    ...
    // save(text); // Move this from here
}

onDestroy()
{
    save(text); // to here.
}
```

---

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle
"Saving activity state" section

> Note: There's no guarantee that onSaveInstanceState() will be called before your activity is destroyed, because there are cases in which it won't be necessary to save the state

Comment: Android document says save in onSaveInstanceState() is NOT guaranteed. And it's for "State".. name tells.

Comment: I should save in onDestroy() ?? I can't call onSave there. So I don't understand how you want me to save. Can you explain more? Tnx

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html has code sample. Just move codes (to save your data) in onSaveInstanceState() to onDestroy().

Comment: I know normal save place is onPause() (or onStop()) but http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html  shows example code using onDestroy().

Comment: They considered about Fragment.setRetainInstance() or Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and chose onDestroy() or just wanted to separate not needed part from onPause() I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
String message;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    //get the list items from savedInstanceState and then notify the adapter
    //for example
    message = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
   //call the api to get the list items
   }
 }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  //save your data here to reuse after rotation
  outState.putString("message", "This is my message to be reloaded");
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

If it's not working , please let me know. And share some code snippet for more clarification.